# How to mock functions from libraries like amqp.Dial

Tags: go, mocking, amqp

I'm working on a small AMQP consumer and i want to test my consumer code, but im struggleing to mock the `amqp.Dial`. I have added some interface so i can mock `Connection` and `Channel` and added a property so i can control the dial-function:

```golang
//consumer.go
type AmqpChannel interface {
    ExchangeDeclare(name, kind string, durable, autoDelete, internal, noWait bool, args amqp.Table) error
    QueueDeclare(name string, durable, autoDelete, exclusive, noWait bool, args amqp.Table) (amqp.Queue, error)
    QueueBind(name, key, exchange string, noWait bool, args amqp.Table) error
    Consume(queue, consumer string, autoAck, exclusive, noLocal, noWait bool, args amqp.Table) (<-chan amqp.Delivery, error)
    Publish(exchange, key string, mandatory, immediate bool, msg amqp.Publishing) error
}

type AmqpConnection interface {
    Channel() (AmqpChannel, error)
    Close() error
}

type AmqpDial func(url string) (AmqpConnection, error)

type MyConsumer struct {
    HostDsn    string
    channel    AmqpChannel
    queue      amqp.Queue
    connection AmqpConnection
    DialFunc   AmqpDial
}

func (c *MyConsumer) Connect() error {
    var err error
    c.connection, err = c.DialFunc(c.HostDsn)
...
```

This seems to be close to what i want to achive, i can specify my test like this:

```golang
func TestConsumer(t *testing.T) {
    mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer mockCtrl.Finish()

    var myConsumer = consumer.MyConsumer{
        HostDsn: "test",
        DialFunc: func(url string) (consumer.AmqpConnection, error) {
            return mocks.NewMockAmqpConnection(mockCtrl), nil
        },
    }
    _ = myConsumer.Connect()
}
```

But i cannot pass the original `amqp.Dial` as dial-func on the main routine:

```golang
myConsumer := consumer.MyConsumer{
        HostDsn: fmt.Sprintf(
            "amqp://%s:%s@rabbitmq:5672/?heartbeat=5s",
            os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_USER"),
            url.QueryEscape(os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD")),
        ),
        DialFunc: amqp.Dial,
    }
```

gives

```
./main.go:28:9: cannot use amqp.Dial (type func(string) (*amqp.Connection, error)) as type consumer.AmqpDial in field value
```

I hoped/thought that, as `amqp.Connection` fulfills the `AmqpConnection` interface, this would work :/
What is the proper way of mocking methods like `amqp.Dial`?

P.S.: im aware of https://github.com/NeowayLabs/wabbit but i would prefer to solve this on a lower level :)

Update: @mkopriva suggested to use another wrapper method, so i tried:

```golang
func getDialer(url string) (consumer.AmqpConnection, error) {
    var connection, err = amqp.Dial(url)
    return connection, err
}
myConsumer := consumer.myConsumer{
        HostDsn: fmt.Sprintf(
            "amqp://%s:%s@rabbitmq:5672/?heartbeat=5s",
            os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_USER"),
            url.QueryEscape(os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD")),
        ),
        DialFunc: getDialer,
    }
```

But this results in:

```
cannot use connection (type *amqp.Connection) as type consumer.AmqpConnection in return argument:
    *amqp.Connection does not implement consumer.AmqpConnection (wrong type for Channel method)
        have Channel() (*amqp.Channel, error)
        want Channel() (consumer.AmqpChannel, error)
make: *** [Makefile:4: build-consumer] Error 2
```

Comment: You can write a wrapper function which does nothing other than invoking `amqp.Dial`. Have this function implement the `AmqpDial` type and use *it* in `main`.

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem, see update :/

Comment: It did solve the problem, you just got a different one now :). The error, while separate from the previous one, represents pretty much the same problem: "type incompatibility". So, again, this can be solved with a wrapper, this time a wrapper struct that implements `consumer.AmqpConnection` and its implementation just delegates to the concrete `*amqp.Connection`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the following types:

```golang
type AmqpChannel interface {
    ExchangeDeclare(name, kind string, durable, autoDelete, internal, noWait bool, args amqp.Table) error
    QueueDeclare(name string, durable, autoDelete, exclusive, noWait bool, args amqp.Table) (amqp.Queue, error)
    QueueBind(name, key, exchange string, noWait bool, args amqp.Table) error
    Consume(queue, consumer string, autoAck, exclusive, noLocal, noWait bool, args amqp.Table) (<-chan amqp.Delivery, error)
    Publish(exchange, key string, mandatory, immediate bool, msg amqp.Publishing) error
}

type AmqpConnection interface {
    Channel() (AmqpChannel, error)
    Close() error
}

type AmqpDial func(url string) (AmqpConnection, error)
```

You can create simple wrappers that delegate to the actual code:

```golang
func AmqpDialWrapper(url string) (AmqpConnection, error) {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return AmqpConnectionWrapper{conn}, nil
}

type AmqpConnectionWrapper struct {
    conn *amqp.Connection
}

// If *amqp.Channel does not satisfy the consumer.AmqpChannel interface
// then you'll need another wrapper, a AmqpChannelWrapper, that implements
// the consumer.AmqpChannel interface and delegates to *amqp.Channel.
func (w AmqpConnectionWrapper) Channel() (AmqpChannel, error) {
    return w.conn.Channel()
}

func (w AmqpConnectionWrapper) Close() error {
    return w.conn.Close()
}
```