# How to handle incompatible concrete return types between an interface and types that implement it in golang?

Tags: go, interface, domain-driven-design, sqlc

I am still learning Go and I decided to use Domain Driven Design with interfaces. I want to support mysql, postgresql and sqlite by choosing the engine at run time depending on the execution environment. Since all the db actions are the same regardless of the engine, I decided to use `sqlc` to generate the db code.

Now I am having a bit of a problem, where I am trying to create an boundary interface  `Storer`  to sit between the consumers and engines and expose db actions to the consumers. It is not working because of incompatible return types that the `Storer` exposes and those that the engines return for each action (method).

Here is an example sqlite implementation of `FindUserById` action that is supposed to return a `user` object:

```golang
package sqlite

/* Begin sqlc generated code */
type User struct {
    ID        string
    FirstName string
    LastName  sql.NullString
    CreatedAt sql.NullTime
}

// findUserById is an sql statement
func (q *Queries) FindUserById(ctx context.Context, id string) (User, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRowContext(ctx, findUserById, id)
    var i User
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.ID,
        &i.FirstName,
        &i.LastName,
        &i.CreatedAt,
    )
    return i, err
}

/* end sqlc generated code */

func (u *User) GetFirstName() string {
    return u.FirstName
}


func NewUserStorer() *Queries { ... }
```

and here is the `storage` package that has the `UserStorer` interface:

```golang
package storage
import "time.Time"

type User struct {
    ID        string
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    CreatedAt time.Time
}
func (u *User) GetFirstName() string {
    return u.FirstName
}
type UserStorer interface {
    FindUserById(ctx context.Context, id string) (User, error)
}
```

Lastly, here is the main package with a`UserStorer` consumer:

```golang
package main

import "MyProject/storage"
import "MyProject/storage/sqlite"
import "fmt"

func ShowFirstName(s storage.UserStorer, id string) {
    u, _ := s.FindUserById(id) //assuming the user exists
    fmt.Println(u.GetFirstName())
}

func main(){
    store := sqlute.NewUserStorer()
    id := "abc123"
    ShowFirstName(store, id)
}
```

Now when I try to call `ShowFirstName`, I get this error:

```golang
cannot use store (variable of type *sqlite.Queries) as storage.UserStorer value in argument to ShowFirstName: *sqlite.Queries does not implement storage.UserStorer(wrong type for method FindUserById)
        have FindUserById(context.Context, string) (sqlite.User, error)
        want FindUserById(context.Context, sql.NullString) (storage.User, error)compilerInvalidIfaceAssign
```

I tried changing the `storage.User` type to be an interface with only the `GetFirstName()` method, but that did not work.
How do I ensure that the return types are the same, and I can swap out sqlite for psql without changing the consumers? I cannot change the code and files generated by `sqlc` to fit the type requirements, and I don't want to write the code it generates manually for maintainability reasons and to avoid sql related errors and bugs.

Comment: For type `T` to implement interface `I`, the type `T`'s method set MUST contain methods that are **identical** to `I`'s whole method set. The methods' names MUST be **identical**. And the methods' input and output parameter types MUST be **identical**. Type `sqlite.User` is NOT identical to `storage.User`, it may implement the interface but that does NOT make it identical. Type `T` is NOT identical to type `I` just because it implements `I`. Also type `string` is not only NOT identical to `sql.NullString`, it can't even implement it since the latter is not an interface type.

Comment: @mkopriva, Thank you for you comment, how would you propose I go about solving this problem, and make the interface be usable by all 3 sql engines?

Comment: To be able to use a dependency in place of an interface it does not implement, you can use the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). This can be achieved by using wrapper types that implement the interface and delegate the calls to the dependency. You'll need to write the wrappers for all 3 engines though (unless the engines themselves share the same interface). Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63149875/965900 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/64513623/965900

Comment: All the engines share a similar interface, that is why I was hoping I could use sqlc to generate the code so i don't have to write it out manually. But I am seeing I will need do more work using it than just writing the code manually, so I have decided to stop using it. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `User` type defined by `sqlc` in the `sqlite` package is not the same as the `User` type defined in the `storage` package. This is because `sqlc` generates its own `User` type with fields that match the columns in the database table, whereas the User type in the storage package has fields that match your domain model.

To solve this problem, we can define a separate User type in your application's domain model that maps to the User type generated by `sqlc`. You can then use this domain model User type in your `UserStorer` interface and in your application's code. Here, we are adapting one interface to another so that two incompatible interfaces can work together ([Adapter Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64513623/8458465)).

```golang
package main

// Write imports here

// Define a domain model User type (storage pkg) that maps to the User type generated by sqlc
type User struct {
    ID        string
    FirstName string
    LastName  sql.NullString
    CreatedAt sql.NullTime
}

// Define a UserMapper interface that maps between sqlc User type and domain model User type
type UserMapper interface {
    FromDB(u *sqlite.User) *storage.User
    ToDB(u *storage.User) *sqlite.User
}

// Implement the UserMapper interface
type sqliteUserMapper struct{}

func (m *sqliteUserMapper) FromDB(u *sqlite.User) *storage.User {
    return &storage.User{
        ID:        u.ID,
        FirstName: u.FirstName,
        LastName:  u.LastName.String,
        CreatedAt: u.CreatedAt.Time,
    }
}
func (m *sqliteUserMapper) ToDB(u *storage.User) *sqlite.User {
    return &sqlite.User{
        ID:        u.ID,
        FirstName: u.FirstName,
        LastName:  sql.NullString{String: u.LastName, Valid: u.LastName != ""},
        CreatedAt: sql.NullTime{Time: u.CreatedAt, Valid: !u.CreatedAt.IsZero()},
    }
}

// Modify your UserStorer interface to use the domain model User type
type UserStorer interface {
    FindUserById(ctx context.Context, id string) (*User, error)
}

// Update your sqlite implementation of FindUserById to use the domain model User type and the UserMapper
func (q *Queries) FindUserById(ctx context.Context, id string) (*storage.User, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRowContext(ctx, findUserById, id)
    var u sqlite.User
    err := row.Scan(&u.ID, &u.FirstName, &u.LastName, &u.CreatedAt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return q.mapper.FromDB(&u), nil
}

// Update your ShowFirstName function to use the domain model User type
func ShowFirstName(s storage.UserStorer, id string) {
    u, _ := s.FindUserById(context.Background(), id) //assuming the user exists
    fmt.Println(u.GetFirstName())
}

// Instantiate your sqlite UserStorer with a UserMapper
func NewUserStorer(mapper storage.UserMapper) *Queries {
    return &Queries{
        db:     db,
        mapper: mapper,
    }
}

func main() {
    // all functions in pkg main to understand the logical order of implementation
    mapper := &sqliteUserMapper{}
    store := sqlite.NewUserStorer(mapper)
    id := "abc123"
    ShowFirstName(store, id)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am seeing `sqlc` is not the best tool for the job here, as I will need to modify the code it generates to make it fit my use case and the docs warn against that. It was my intention to use the adapter from the start and thought I could use sqlc to assist with that. I will rewrite the interfaces and use my own code but with the guidance sqlc and your answer provided.